# Using C/C++ <Thread> in my program?

Tags: c, multithreading

I want to be sure whether I should use `<thread>` in my code. 
I am writting for a simple console game. It's like the letters I input fall down from the top of the console and I can remove them one by one by typing each letter  in a real time. ( for the purpose of remembering names quickly. )

I think It should be split it into 2 parts, the one printing out the random letters which is falling down to the bottom( If it passes the bottom, get -1 from the life gauge )  and   the other one waiting for the letters, which is to use for removal. ).

Both seem to need each processor to run on console in a real time and  Message passing is necessary for matching letters.

Comment: Please do not tag both C and C++ as the answer will differ. Which language are you actually using?

Comment: You also haven't asked an actual question.

Comment: Should I use thread on my program, It was my question. You have't read precisely though. NathanOliver.

Comment: Sounds simple enough for a single thread, but that is not an argument for not using threads - the question is largely a matter of opinion, but if you want to learn about threading, then starting with something simple is not a bad idea - just be aware that it will probably complicate this simple application.  C does not support threading directly - that is provided by the OS or operating environment and accessed through a library.

Comment: thank you so much, I will try using it.

Comment: I thought Using thread is the only way ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that even though your application needs to perform seemingly parallel things, this does not automatically implies that you have to use multiple threads. Your task can be easily solved in a single thread, using an event loop for example.

Usually multi-threading is useful in just a couple of situations: 1) you need a computing performance, doing computations in parallel on multi-core system; 2) there are blocking operations (e.g. network or disc I/O) that affect other parts of the application (GUI responsiveness for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You could use multithreading for this, but frankly, I wouldn't.

What you need to remember is that what a time period that's short enough to be simultaneous to a human is a small eternity to a computer. Or even a long one, depending on application.

What'll probably make your life a heck of a lot easier is something like this (pseudocode):

```
while (true) {
  // moves letters down, spawns them at the top, checks if they've fallen off the screen
  updateFallingLetters();
  // polls for input, updates game state accordingly
  checkIfIHaveInput();
  // waits until one thirtieth or one sixtieth or whatever of a second has passed.
  sleepUntilFrameRateAfterLastIWasHere();
}
```

Comment: The above one is more informative for a beginner like me, but your answer helps, too. Wish I could select yours too.